# How do I type a class in typescript that dynamically loads its own members

Tags: javascript, class, typescript, types

Hi I'm using `typescript 2.1.4` and I have this issue.

Imagine that I have a `object` that looks like this

```
interface IObj{
    key1:ISubObj;
}
interface ISubObj{
    exp:RegExp;
    method:(param:string)=>boolean
}
const obj:IObj={
    key1: {
        exp: /someexp/i,
        method: somemethod
    }
}
```

and `somemethod` looks like this

```
function somemethod(regexp){
   return function(param){
       return regexp.test(param)
   }
}
```

In type script I have created a class that looks like this

```
export class someClass {
 constructor(obj) {
    for (let k in obj) {
        this[k]=obj[k].method(obj[k].exp)
    }
    return this;
 }
}
export const Foo = new someClass(obj);
```

The problem I am running into is that this parses to valid `javascript` however, using `Foo.key1(param)` returns a type `error`. `key1` does not exists on Foo.

I have used the `implements someInterface` on the class but the interface is only valid if I use `key1` as optional. I would prefer not to use the optional syntax

```
interface someInterface {
    key1?:(param:string)=>boolean
}
export class someClass implements someInterface{...}
```

Is there a way to create valid types on dynamically constructed classes?

### EDIT

Corrected typo where obj was not passed into constructor

### EDIT

Using @toskv answer i changed my solution slightly to get what I wanted which worked. It may not be the best way though

```
interface IObj{
    key1:ISubObj;
}
interface ISubObj{
    exp:RegExp;
    method:(param:string)=>boolean
}
const obj:IObj={
    key1: {
        exp: /someexp/i,
        method: somemethod
    }
}
export interface ISomeClass{
   key1:(str:string)=>boolean;
}
export type TSomeClass<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]?=T[P]
}
export class someClass {
 constructor(obj) {
    for (let k in obj) {
        this[k]=obj[k].method(obj[k].exp)
    }
    return this;
 }
}
export const Foo:TSomeClass<ISomeClass> = new someClass(obj);
```

Comment: does obj have a type specific type or can it be anything?

Comment: @toskv obj will continue to follow the same pattern so it will be typed as you see it. I edited to show obj type;

Comment: btw.. this might not be the issue but.. you are not actually passing **obj** to the constructor. :)

Answer (score 1):

There might be better ways of doing this but here's something to start with.

You can use **mappedTypes** added in 2.1 to create a new type based on the IObj interface.

```js
interface IObj {
  key1: ISubObj;
}
interface ISubObj {
  exp: RegExp;
  method: (param: string) => boolean
}

type Result = {
  // must be optional so we can initialize it with nothing
  [P in keyof IObj]?: boolean
}

class Mine {
  // it's not really a property of the class but hey it's typed
  public results: Result = {};

  constructor(obj: IObj) {
    for (let k in obj) {
      this.results[k] = obj[k].method(obj[k].exp)
    }
    return this;
  }
}

// autocomplete and everything
new Mine(null).results.key1
```

[Here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20IObj%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20key1%3A%20ISubObj%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Ainterface%20ISubObj%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20exp%3A%20RegExp%3B%0D%0A%20%20method%3A%20(param%3A%20string)%20%3D%3E%20boolean%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20Result%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%5BP%20in%20keyof%20IObj%5D%3F%3A%20boolean%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Mine%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20public%20results%3A%20Result%20%3D%20%7B%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20constructor(obj%3A%20IObj)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20for%20(let%20k%20in%20obj)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20this.results%5Bk%5D%20%3D%20obj%5Bk%5D.method(obj%5Bk%5D.exp)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20this%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Anew%20Mine(null).results.key1%0D%0A)'s an example in the playground.

You can read more about mapped types in the [2.1 release notes](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#typescript-21).

In this case the class doesn't really make sense though. A function that transforms the data works just as well.

```js
function testIObj(obj: IObj): Result {
  let results: Result = {};
  for (let k in obj) {
    results[k] = obj[k].method(obj[k].exp)
  }
  return results;
}


testIObj(null).key1;
```

That allows you to do nice things like processing an entire list of them easily.

If you the **method** functions will return different types it's relatively easy to extend to accomdate for them as well.

```js
 type Result = {
      // must be optional so we can initialize it with nothing
      [P in keyof IObj]?: boolean | number
    }
```

Comment: This works well in your case as a function however, there are two concerns. one -> I am trying to keep the simple namespace Foo.key1() and two ->  `[P in keyof IObj]?: boolean` should actually be ` [P in keyof T]?:T[P]` to make this less confusing and more dynamic. but that leads to extra complexity for the other interfaces. I attempted to implement your solution but it is not very extensible...

Comment: looking at the code in the constructor of your class the property values would the result of calling the method function from the IObject interface and that returns boolean, thus the type of the result value is boolean too (unless those methods could return something else I see nothing wrong with that). As for the Foo.key1().. I guess that could be done if you don't use the class but just have a function that creates something of the defined typed (not everything has to be classes).

Comment: I agree with "not everything needs to be a class" but i have some plans and using classes may help with organizing the structure. this is the simplest version of my methods...more to come @toskv

Answer (score 0):

This could work based on @toskv answer. Do you see issues with this other than having to update two interfaces?

```
interface IObj{
    key1:ISubObj;
}
interface ISubObj{
    exp:RegExp;
    method:(param:string)=>boolean
}
const obj:IObj={
    key1: {
        exp: /someexp/i,
        method: somemethod
    }
}
export interface ISomeClass{
   key1:(str:string)=>boolean;
}
export type TSomeClass<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]?=T[P]
}
export class someClass {
 constructor(obj) {
    for (let k in obj) {
        this[k]=obj[k].method(obj[k].exp)
    }
    return this;
 }
}
export const Foo:TSomeClass<ISomeClass> = new someClass(obj);
```

Comment: why the class though? are there other methods on someClass besides the one that creates the stuff?

Comment: Also keep in mind that T[P] is actually the type (param: string) => boolean. As it is it doesn't correctly describes what the actual value will be (that being boolean).